# Django - how to access local audio files in different URL paths?

Tags: django

Thanks in advance for reading. I'm working on my final project for CS50W which involves working with a series of local audio files (user cannot upload additional files at this time). The issue occurs when I try to populate an  src attribute with the file. I have two URL paths which deal with accessing these files: new/ and edit/int:id. When I access the audio files in new/, it works as intended and I can play the file from the  tag. However, when I try to access the files in the edit/int:id path, I get this error:

GET http://localhost/edit/8/media/Aminor_Ipi3udk.mp3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I am relatively new to coding (just did CS50x and then started CS50w) and I don't understand why I'm getting this error or how I can fix it - I'm doing the same thing for both paths and yet it only works in one of them. I would be grateful if someone could help me to remedy this or at least point me in the direction of understanding why this is happening.

views.py

```
def edit(request, id):
    song = Song.objects.get(id=id)
    sections = Section.objects.filter(song=song).order_by('order')
    chords = Chord.objects.all()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "songbud/edit.html", {
            'song':song,
            'sections':sections,
            'chords':chords
            })
```

songbud.js

```
function select_audio_edit(elem) {
    var parent_Node = elem.parentNode;
    console.log(parent_Node.childNodes);
    var file = parent_Node.childNodes[3].options[parent_Node.childNodes[3].selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-file');
    //console.log(file);
    //console.log(parent_Node.childNodes);
    parent_Node.childNodes[5].setAttribute("src", file);

    return false;
};

function fill_audio() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#chordtemp");
    elements.forEach(div => {
        let chord = div.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        Array.from(div.childNodes[3].options).forEach(function(option_element) {
            if (option_element.text == chord) {
                option_element.selected = true;
                let file = option_element.dataset.file;
                console.log(file);
                div.childNodes[5].setAttribute("src", file);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

edit.html

```
{% extends "songbud/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="songcreate" style="margin: 30px; font-family: 'Courier New';">
        <h1 id="song-title">{{ song.title }}</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="addsection" onclick="return add_section()">+ add section</button>
    </div>
    {% for section in sections %}
        <div style="display: block; margin: 20px;" id='sectiontemplate'>
            <label for='sectiontype'>Choose a section:</label> 
            <br>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name='sectiontype' id='sectiontype' style="display: inline-block;"> 
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Intro' %}
                    <option selected>Intro</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option >Intro</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Verse' %}
                    <option selected>Verse</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Verse</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Chorus' %}
                    <option selected>Chorus</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Chorus</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Bridge' %}
                    <option selected>Bridge</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Bridge</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Interlude' %}
                    <option selected>Interlude</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Interlude</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Breakdown' %}
                    <option selected>Breakdown</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Breakdown</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Solo' %}
                    <option selected>Solo</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Solo</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if section.sectiontype == 'Outro' %}
                    <option selected>Outro</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option>Outro</option>
                {% endif %}
            </select>
            
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="addchord" onclick='add_chord(this)' style="display: inline-block;">+ add chord</button>
            <br>
            {% for chord in section.chords %}
                <div id='chordtemp'>
                    <p style='display: none;'>{{ chord }}</p>
                    <select name="chordselect" id="chordselect" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: center;" onchange="return select_audio_edit(this)">
                        {% for chrd in chords %}
                            <option data-file="media/{{ chrd.file }}">{{ chrd }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <audio controls id='audiofile' style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 23px;">
                        <source src="" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- These are the templates for sections and chords -->
    <div style='display:none;' data-type='sectiontemplate' id='sectiontemplate'>
        <label for='sectiontype'>Choose a section:</label> 
        <br>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name='sectiontype' id='sectiontype' style="display: inline-block;"> 
            <option>Intro</option>
            <option>Verse</option>
            <option>Chorus</option>
            <option>Bridge</option>
            <option>Interlude</option>
            <option>Breakdown</option>
            <option>Solo</option>
            <option>Outro</option>
        </select>
        
        <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="addchord" onclick='add_chord(this)' style="display: inline-block;">+ add chord</button>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div style='display:none;' data-type='chordtemplate' id='chordtemplate'>
        <select name="chordselect" id="chordselect" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: center;" onchange="return select_audio(this)">
            {% for chord in chords %}
                <option data-file="media/{{ chord.file }}">{{ chord }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <audio controls style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 23px;">
            <source src="" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="savesong" onclick="return save_song()">save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="exportsong" onclick="return export_song_edit()">export</button>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'songbud/songbud.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `/media/...` instead of `media/...` to make the URLs absolute.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show your code here directly. It should be a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are asking about.

Comment: To clarify some terminology, you are not really accessing "local files" here. A "local file" is one that you access directly from your harddrive with a path like "C:\Users\bh96\Documents\audio.mp3". From the point of view of the HTML in the web page, it is making a request to a web server. That webserver happens to be accessed by the address `http://localhost`, but it could just as easily be `http://example.com`.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, you can enter `http://localhost/edit/8/media/Aminor_Ipi3udk.mp3` into the address bar of any web browser to see what happens. You can then edit the URL to try to find the correct path. As AKX suggests, you should try `http://localhost/media/Aminor_Ipi3udk.mp3`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the terminology - I'm definitely still learning a lot so thats's helpful. Taking out the /edit/#/ does indeed work - however, I don't know how to make it so that when my javascript function fills the audio src, it automatically removes the edit/# from the URL.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm wondering if you could provide any more help. I don't know how to resolve the issue with the URL - you're correct that removing the edit/# from the URL causes the media to be played, but I'm unsure how to make it so that django automatically uses that URL to retrieve the media file. Like I said, it works when I use the new/ url path but not with the edit/ path.

Comment: @bh96 What more help do you need? AKX already told you the solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Unfortunately, adding the leading slash did not resolve the issue - nor did adding {{ chord.file.url }}. I'm still getting that 404 error whenever I try to fill the audio src.

Comment: @bh96 What URL does `chord.file.url` give? If you still need help, please [edit] your question to show the `Chord` model class and the `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix here is to change `media/{{ chord.file }}` to `/media/{{ chord.file }}`. However, you shouldn't be manually creating this path in the first place. I think you can do `{{ chord.file.url }}` instead. Here I'm assuming that `chord` is a model object with a `FileField` named `file`. I suggest you check the documentation for `FileField` to verify this and understand it better.